# Android - Access URL from a Service (Http Request)

Tags: java, android, http, url, sharedpreferences

I'm working on an App, that I have an HTTP request. Which I call a Service. But my problem is that the requested URL is set by the user on an EditText inside the Fragment. I'm saving the field's text with shared preferences but when my fragment died its return a null pointer in the URL. I set the URL like this:

```
 HttpConnection.getSetDataWeb(Fragment.myUrl);
```

I want to know how can I save this attribute (my URL) in a way that will be always saved for me to call in my service.

I know that is a bit confuse... Sorry..

Thanks!

Comment: Before you use it in your Service, check if it's null, and if it is, retrieve it from SharedPreferences.

Comment: Store URL in shared preference or in Application class and use it. before to use check the value is null or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this in your Service to make sure that your SharedPreference isn't empty:

```
if(url == null)
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("FILEKEY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    url = prefs.getString("myurl", null);
}
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for answer. I did not understand  why pass ("myurl", null). Why null? the problem is that the fragment that contains the data is not my main fragment, so , for example, when i kill my application and start again, the service returns a null pointer on the url...

Comment: The null is just the default if the SharedPreference does not find the URL (for example if you have not saved it yet). You can change it to something else.